# View Recap Pro Projects in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have just discovered a new function that I have been waiting for for a very long time.

It is now possible to publish Recap Pro projects to the cloud for viewing and annotating. [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiZvSLc2GaY)

if I have seen it correctly , its atm only possible in BIM360 Docs, but here the Forge Viewer is used.

Now my question:

When will this function be made available to me as a developer?

Answer (score 0):

BIM 360 Docs is built on top of the Forge Viewer, it should be already available for you to translate the model and display it in your own application.

Something you might want to try is to upload the RCP file to BIM 360 and then get the URN from there to pass it to your custom made viewer, so it takes care of the needed setup for translation.

Comment: Uploading the RCP file or the complete folder (tryed with raw files and in .zip format) to OSS works but the file cannot be translated and cannot be opened. Same for Autodesk Drive and Autodesk Viewer.
The only option to get it working was to publish the RCP project via Autodesk Connector directly from Recap Pro to Autodesk Drive. Then i am able to launch the viewer but only in my connected Autodesk Drive folder.
But copying the urn and trying to access it from my custom viewer does not work (404 Error).